# Laravel 5.4 Routes

Tags: php, laravel

I currently have several routes in Laravel 5 but I want to combine them so instead of them being separate, I want them grouped, how can I do this?

```
Route::get('url1', function() {
    return Redirect::to('/');
}

Route::get('url2', function() {
    return Redirect::to('/');
}

Route::get('url3', function() {
    return Redirect::to('/');
}
```

How can I make just a single route so I dont have to repeat it like maybe:

```
Route::get('url1','url2','url3', function(){
    return Redirect::to('/');
});
```

**Thank You.**

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Wait, is url1 and url2 completely different? Or like example.com/1 and example.com/2? Do they have something in common?

Comment: I think grouping them is the way to go(not sure though cause I dont have a laravel project atm to test this): https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#route-groups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression for your routes:

```
Route::get('{url}', function ($name) {
    Redirect::to('/');
})->where('url', 'url[0-9]+');
```

This will redirect all routes with a number behind url

If they are different you can use the same logic:

```
Route::get('{url}', function ($name) {
    Redirect::to('/');
})->where('url', 'url1|url2|url3');
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this code.you can use a dynamic route parameter. Let me know your thoughts?

```
Route::get('{slug?}', function($slug = 'index')
{
    return Redirect::to('/');
})->where('slug', '(url1|url2|url3)');
```

Answer (score 0):

Or just with a `foreach` loop :)

```
foreach(['url1', 'url2', 'url3'] as $url)
{
    Route::get($url, function() {
        return Redirect::to('/');
    }
}
```